# Расширение для VSCode из Brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

Кто работал с Brackets (текстовый редактор для веб-разработчиков), сталкивался в нем с Live Preview который помогает в разработке real-time редактировать css свойства и видеть его изменение в chrom'e. И также второй инструмент CSS Peek который позволяет наведя курсор на контейнер div с классом .content и нажав Ctrl+E и если у .content прописаны стили в css файле проекта, редактировать свойства в маленьком выпадающем окошке в HTML файле не переходя в сам файл css . В скринах будет пример поведение CSS Peek. Если такие расширения в VSCode , кто знает поделитесь плиз. Это помогает писать разметку
[image: пример функционала в Brackets]

Comment: Для просмотра изменений, сделанных в простом html - проекте, есть расширение GoLive. Про стили - не знаю, расширение, которое Вы описали - это прямо то, чего не хватает. Если такого нет - его нужно срочно написать! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил - есть такое расширение для VSC, называется ровно так же - [CSS Peek](https://github.com/abierbaum/vscode-file-peek).

Не могу сказать, насколько оно хуже или лучше, чем то, которое показано на картинке.

Судя по строчкам в описании -

Peek: load the css file inline and make quick edits right there. (Ctrl+Shift+F12)

Go To: jump directly to the css file or open it in a new editor (F12)

Hover: show the definition in a hover over the symbol (Ctrl+hover)

оно функционально должно делать то же самое.

Выглядит примерно так:

[image: картинка из их гитхаба]

А для просмотра изменений есть расширание GoLive - вроде бы, простой HTTP - сервер, который вешается на 5500 порт и показывает все изменения в проекте - перезагружает страницу само, после того, как в проект внесены изменения.